# Reading with InputStream while using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I want to read from a client's `inputstream` in two different ways:

1: Use `Scanner` over the `inputstream` to read strings.

2: Use the `InputStream` object itself to read a file with a buffer.

At first, I want to read a text, that gives me the name and size of the File, in my case: "file:name:...", "file:size:...".

When I have this information, the `InputStream` should actually read the file. The problem is, that I try to read the file in the "`scanner.hasNextLine()`"-loop with the `InputStream` object but this causes the `InputStream.read()` method to return -1 or EOS. I have brought the problem to a minimal size so you just have to answer me this question:

Why does the read-method return -1 here:

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {        
    System.out.println(inputstream.read());
}
```

Comment: Please include more code. The easy answer to "Why ... -1" is that end of file was reached, and that's no help.

Comment: Why do you read through ``Scanner`` **and** ``InputStream``?

Comment: I use `Scanner` and `InputStream` because with the `Scanner`, I want to read the incoming commands and with the `InputStream` I want to read the file which can be **different** from a text file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I don't need `Scanner` **and** `InputStream` anymore. I can do both, sending texts and files, with the `DataOutputStream` (with `writeUTF(String)` and `write(byte[], int, int)`). This really works very well and simplifies my code a lot.

Don't say this is dobious! If you have a `Socket`, sometimes you need to use the `InputStream` in two or three different ways. And I didn't want to use two Sockets.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) for `Scanner.hasNextLine()` states, this method *does not* advance the `Scanner`. This means that you could be perpetually looking at the first line of your file with your `Scanner`, while advancing your `InputStream`. This means that even though the `Scanner` has a next line, the `InputStream` may not. You appear to be walking off the end of the file with the `InputStream`.

If you do not advance the `Scanner` along with the input stream, you cannot know that the `Scanner` is looking at the same location in the file. It is dubious at best to read one file simultaneously with a `Scanner` and an `InputStream` anyway.

Consider refactoring your code to only use one or the other.

If you would like to read the entire contents of the file into a single `String`, consider this:

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
  throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

and other methods from [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)